# What is the sense of using types like wchar_t?

Tags: c, types, wchar-t

I've looked through some answers and articles which state that `wchar_t` is used to store unicode symbols encoded as `utf-16`. That makes sense, but...

Doesn't variable contents depend on how it is treated or formatted? We can take an `int` variable and format it as a character. We can take `short` which is 2 bytes long too and format it as a character as well, thus obtaining the same 2-byte character. That never raised any errors, at least in my experience. Moreover, as far as I'm aware, a compiler may indeed treat a character as of an `int` type.

Why do types like `wchar_t` or `char16_t` even exist? Cannot types like `short` be used instead? Is it just a convention, or `wchar_t` and `short` work differently indeed?

Comment: Using type-aliases like that also gives specific semantic meaning to the types. `short` could be any kind of "short" integer, the use of the integer is unknown for a casual reader. But for `wchar_t` we can assume that it stores a wide character.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well sound like you assert that `wchar_t` is just a convention for readability

Comment: Not only "just", but high readability leads to high maintainability. It's a good thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude readability is cool, I didn't say anything against that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the sense of using types like wchar_t?

The represent a wide character on a particular platform.

> Why do types like wchar_t or char16_t even exist?

Why does any type exists - we could just use `long long` for everything? Why does C language exists? To give programmers abstraction over machine. Different types in a C programming language exists as an abstraction over machine/platform specific types, so that different C compilers may compile the same code to different machine instructions depending on the platform. Same code that uses `wchar_t` may be compiled for windows and for linux and create different executable, with same functionality. Different types exists to abstract different things - a `short` represents a short number,  a `wchar_t` represents a wide character. These abstraction are there to give compilers freedom how to represent these semantics in machine code and also to allow programmers write readable code.

> Cannot types like short be used instead?

On a platform where `short` can represent all values that `wchar_t` can, then `short` may be used to store a wide character value. That is not anyhow guaranteed. In simple terms, `wchar_t` may have more bytes then `short`. There may be a wide character that can't be represented in a `short` type. There's also alignment requirements. Similar for `char16_t`.

`char16_t` is the same type as `uint_least16_t`, you may use it instead. Sure the standard could have used exact 16-bit variable, but operations using 16-bit registers may be ridiculously slow on a particular machine. So standards gives compilers freedom - choose the type that he wants.

> Is it just a convention, or wchar_t and short work differently indeed?

You can say, the whole C language is just a convention. Creating a convention, gives other people something to abstract from/to and to refer to. Standardizing that conventions gives a basis to portability. Portability is when you can write code for one platform and run it on another platform without concern. You *could* use `short` on a particular platform instead of `wchar_t`, *but* your code will fail suprisingly on other platforms.

Comment: whatever, a perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

The size of a wchar_t is not guaranteed across platforms. In Linux, a wchar_t is 4 bytes, but in Windows or AIX it's 2 bytes. That is why the data type has been abstracted out, its left as a platform implementation detail. The wide character was created to support multi-byte character, but before there was a Unicode implementation that platforms would support. Additionally, the encoding of wide characters can also change depending on the platform.

Comment: The size of `short` is not guaranteed too, what is the point then?

Comment: (On AIX, size of `wchar_t` is different for 32/64-bit application: 2 vs 4 bytes.)

Comment: @Kaiyaha The point is that the detail is abstracted away from the developer. Instead of having ifdefs for each platform, you can just use the wchar_t type and have the platform take care of it, and you have a consistent library to check wide character properties (wcslen, wcsncpy, etc)

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond, thank you for catching that. I guess I only tinkered with 32 bit AIX systems when working with wide characters

Answer (score 0):

The size of the type `short` is platform-dependent. So if you need to use an integer with exactly 16 bits you can use `int16_t` or `uint16_t` types.

Using the type `wchar_t` makes code independent of the underlying type (that is platform-dependent) of `wchar_t`. For example functions that uses the type `wchar_t` can be declared equally independent on the underlying integer type for the type `wchar_t`.

The C Standard defines the type `wchar_t` as an integer type.

```
wchar_t
```

> which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct
> codes for all  members of the largest extended character set specified
> among the supported locales;

Usually the type `wchar_t` is defined as an alias for the type `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` that is called the  underlying type of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Isn't `wchar_t` platform-dependent too? I thought that is the reason why `char16_t` exists

Comment: @Kaiyaha I wrote that it can have platform-dependent underlined type. "Using the type wchar_t makes code independent of the underlined type of wchar_t"

Comment: @didn't really get what you said, what is an `underlined type`? do you mean types with underscores?

Comment: @Kaiyaha It means that the type is defined in the header stddef.h usually either as uint16_t or uint32_t. Such a type is called underlined type.

Comment: Any sources? Google says nothing about `underlined types` in C or C++

Comment: @Kaiyaha I am sorry. I made a typo. I meant the word " underlying".:) English is not my native language.:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223843/discussion-between-vlad-from-moscow-and-kaiyaha).

Answer (score 0):

`wchar_t` is intended as a general "wide" character type, not specifically UTF-16:

> **7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**
> ...
> 2    The types are
> ...
>         **`wchar_t`**
> which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all
> members of the *largest extended character set specified among the supported locales*; the
> null character shall have the code value zero. Each member of the basic character set
> shall have a code value equal to its value when used as the lone character in an integer
> character constant if an implementation does not define
> **`_ _STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC_ _`**.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.

The number of distinct values that the largest supported extended character set contains may be greater than what the current platform's `short` can represent; it may be significantly smaller.  `wchar_t` will be sized appropriately for that.

Do not think about types in terms of the number of bytes they occupy - the C language definition certainly doesn't.  It defines the various types in terms of the *minimum ranges of values they must be able to represent*.  A `short` must be able to represent all the values in *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`, meaning the type must contain *at least* 16 value bits, but it may be wider.

On most modern real machines native word sizes are 32 or 64 bits and everything's broken down into 8-bit bytes, but that is neither required nor guaranteed.

Types *matter* in C, and `wchar_t` and `short` mean different things and imply different behaviors.